# display array as image in mean stack (node+angular etc..)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, mongodb, display

I have an "object" persona with an attribute that I recovered from MongoDB. The array its a:

```
persona.faceDetection.photo=[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,1....etc]
var encodedData = window.btoa(persona.faceDetection.photo);
persona.faceDetection.photo=encodedData;
```

and then I represent it with angular like:

```
 <img data-ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{newPersona.faceDetection.photo}}" /img>
```

but dont display nothing. Is there any way more simple?
PD:sorry about my english and from my code, im very noob at this.

Comment: `photo` object must be base64. Try something like 
`var myBase64 = window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(persona.faceDetection.photo)));`

Comment: It worked for me!!! thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as an answer

`<image src data:image/jpeg;base64` requires base64 as implied.

So `persona.faceDetection.photo` object must be base64.

Try something like

```
    var myUint8 = new Uint8Array(persona.faceDetection.photo)
    var myBase64 = window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, myUint8)); 

    persona.faceDetection.photo=myBase64 ;
```